# Are Nextjs' data fetching systems and functions one-to-one at the top level?

Tags: next.js

I create web client app with Next.js.
I have a question.

If there are two similar functions in the same hierarchy, such as

```
function Hoge({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
     {data.hoge}
    </div>
  )
}
function Fuga({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
     {data.fuga}
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  ...
  return {
    props: {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

, **which one will be called?**

Or is this against the rules?

I couldn't find any source code or documentation that shows which function is called.

Comment: You can only `export default` one of them. That will be the component that gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a page directory (inside of the pages folder) you can't have 2 components there. Only 1 component that represents your page and is exported by default. Now if this isn't inside of the said directory, you can't call getStaticProps inside of it. The fetching methods, are to be called inside of a page file. So this scenario is impossible.
The documentation could be more in details if you are interested:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props